# What happens if CT ratio entered wrong in 3phase meter

Tags: meter

I have HT connection with [PREMIER 300 - SECURE METER](http://securemeters.com/index.php/global/products/generation/premier-300/),
CT operated at 5:2.5. But in the meter, the ratio is showing 1 instead of 0.5. 
My question is whether the ratio matters or not.

Comment: My response is that capitals matter. If you have a product name in your question then it is not clear because the capital letters are missing. So is the link to the datasheet for the meter.

Answer (score 5):

If your meter is assuming one ratio, and it's actually a different ratio, then the meter will read incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually 7-8 months ago the PF is above 90 for 20 to 30 KVA load and 20 KVAR capacitor. From some months the PF decreases very low at same load and same capacitor now to catch the PF connected 60 KVAR capacitor for same load what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the ratio matters. You will get incorrect reading.

Furthermore the applied burden can influence the transformers ratio. So please ensure that you are using the right transformer for the right burden.